# Inverse of a real-square symmetric block-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a larger real-square symmetric matrix for which the diagonal elements are smaller real-square symmetric matrices like:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{V} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}_1  &  0   & \cdots  & 0  \\
0           &  \mathbf{V}_2    &  \cdots  & 0  \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
 0 &  0 &  \cdots &  \mathbf{V}_m \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Instead of inverting $\mathbf{V}$ to get $\mathbf{V}^{-1}$, can I simply invert each smaller matrix, $\mathbf{V}_i$, and then replace $\mathbf{V}_i$ with its inverse?  (fyi, I am using the QR method).

The context is that I noticed a commercial software package inverted an e.g. $\sim16000 \times 16000 $ $\mathbf{V}$ matrix in less than a second, so I am thinking there's no way the entire matrix was inverted, rather, each $\mathbf{V}_i$ was inverted singly(?)

Comment: Yes you can: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion

Comment: Thanks - I provided an answer since moderators don't like unanswered questions that are not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Emilio Novati, looking at that page, the translation would be, for my particular case:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}  &  \mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{C}  &  \mathbf{D} \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
      -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1} \\
    -\left(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
       \left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and then by substitution of $\mathbf{B}=\bf{0}$ and $\mathbf{D}=\bf{0}$, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}  &  \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0}  &  \mathbf{D} \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}^{-1}  &  \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0}  &  \mathbf{D}^{-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}